# Is it better to use MSMQ or a webservice for logging?

Tags: database, web-services, logging, msmq

Is it better to use an MSMQ or a webservice for logging alerts messages to database?
Instead of direct DB access, MSMQ or a webservice is much efficient so which one would be most useful in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that logging should be local to the component in a distributed system. Then there is no dependency on a centralised resource being available.

However, assuming you want a centralised database log, I would suggest sending a message to a MSMQ queue local to the database server.

This way the database service does not even need to be available and you can still queue log entries which will be delivered and processed offline when the database server becomes available.

Comment: I donot know the size of data to be logged and the number of logs that mite happen in a day so will the queue not overflow?I can set the size of queue but after that i should have some mechanism to clear the logs automatically.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you would be down long enough for your queue to fill up. It can happen though. When you read from the queue that removes the queue message so you won't need something the clear down the queue.